# How do I display a SQLite table in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtableview, qtsql

I am trying to connect to a local database and show a table in QTableView. I am currently getting a connection to my database but whenever I try to append my query to the QTableView box i am getting `QSqlError("", "Unable to find table projects", "")`. When I run `SELECT * FROM projects` in DB browser for SQLite, the entry I have in that table shows up. Here is my mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "purchaseorder.h"
#include <QtSql>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    PurchaseOrder *newpo = new PurchaseOrder();

    QSqlDatabase db;

    bool openDB(){
        db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
        db.setDatabaseName("projectmanager.db");

        if(!db.open())
        {
            qDebug()<<"Error opening database" << db.lastError();
            return false;
        }else{
            qDebug()<<"Connection Established.";
            return true;
        }
    }

    void closeDB(){
        db.close();
        //db.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
    }

private slots:
    void on_actionProject_2_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    PurchaseOrder purchaseorder;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here is a snippet of my mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QtSql>

void MainWindow::on_actionProject_2_triggered()     // Load PROJECT table
{
    QSqlTableModel* modal = new QSqlTableModel();
    MainWindow conn;

    conn.openDB();

    modal->setTable("projects");
    modal->select();
    ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
    qDebug()<<modal->lastError();

    conn.close();
}
```

I believe everything is working up until. `modal->setTable("projects");`
Also I have my `projectmanager.db` file stored in `/db/projectmanager.db` but when I put that in my db path it does not connect but it will connect the way I have it? Thank you for any help, all is appreciated.

Desc. of projects:

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` ( `project_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,   
`project_name` TEXT,
`client` INTEGER,
`lead_employee` INTEGER,
`description` TEXT,
`start_date` TEXT,
`deadline` TEXT,
`status` INTEGER )
```

Comment: `QSqlDatabase db;` It is [highly recommended](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#details) that `QSqlDatabase` types not be used as member variables. Please provide a _[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_. Right now, your question is _kinda_ close but not yet complete. (e.g. sample database data?)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Thank you for the suggestion I have added the table that I am trying to acquire. Please let me know if there is more that I can provide.

Comment: Is `/db/projectmanager.db` the full file path? If not, replace it with the full path. (If the best you could work with is a relative path, consider using _[QDir](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#absoluteFilePath)_.)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS The full path is `C:/Users/jorda/Documents/divisionrepo/tdproject/db/projectmanager.db` I should have mentioned in the problem that I had tried this as well with the same result (Connection Established, Cannot find table projects).

Comment: @TrebuchetMS if I delete the .db file from that path it still runs as well with "Connection established.".

Comment: @Jordan execute:  `qDebug()<<db.tables();`

Comment: @eyllanesc When I run that i get `()` as the output although when I commented out the db initialization in my mainwindow.h and declared it in my .cpp file it showed all of the tables

Comment: @Jordan You do not need to create another MainWindow, you have to open the connection before creating the model.

Comment: @eyllanesc that worked! thank you for your help. I'm still confused as to why `conn` was useless though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the connection before creating the model, on the other hand it is not necessary to create another MainWindow, so the solution is:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionProject_2_triggered()
{
    openDB();
    QSqlTableModel *modal = new QSqlTableModel;
    modal->setTable("projects");
    modal->select();
    ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
    closeDB();
}
```